# How to create database file into msi file for clickonce

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am developing a CMS based application and I want that my application should install the database automatically while installing the application. How can I create a MSI file so that I can install my database automaitcally on startup.

Answer (score 2):

You can either

1) include the .mdf/.ldf files for an "empty" database into your MSI and place them in the right directory for SQL Server and then use e.g. `sqlcmd.exe` to attach those database files to the server

OR:

2) you could include a bunch of scripts to create this database into your project, and have some utility (e.g. [SSW's SQL Deploy](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/SQLDeploy/)) execute those scripts in a given order, to create the database, database objects, and seed the lookup / system tables

OR:

3) you could look into Microsoft's new WebDeploy technology - it allows you to deploy a web app including stuff like IIS configuration and database scripts to a new machine.

- [Web Deploy 2.0 Home Page](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy)
- [Web Deployment Made Awesome: If You're Using XCopy, You're Doing It Wrong](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx)